# pig REPLACE gives error

Tags: replace, apache-pig

Let's assume that my file is named 'data' and looks like this:

2343234  {23.8375,-2.339921102}     {(343.34333,-2.0000022)}   5-23-2013-11-am

I need to convert the 2nd field to a pair of coordinate numbers. So I wrote the follwoing code and called it basic.pig:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (f1:int, f2:chararray, f3:chararray. f4:chararray);

B = foreach A generate STRSPLIT(f2,',').$0 as f5, STRSPLIT(f2,',').$1 as f6;

C = foreach B generate REPLACE(f5,'{',' ') as f7, REPLACE(f6,'}',' ') as f8;
```

and then used (float) to convert the string to a float. But, the command 'REPLACE' fails to work and I get the following error:

```
-bash-3.2$ pig -x local basic.pig 


2013-06-24 16:38:45,030 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1 (r1459641) compiled 

Mar 22 2013, 02:13:53 2013-06-24 16:38:45,031 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/--/p/--test/pig_1372117125028.log

2013-06-24 16:38:45,321 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/isl/pmahboubi/.pigbootup not found

2013-06-24 16:38:45,425 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///

2013-06-24 16:38:46,069 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 7, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""

Details at logfile: /home/--/p/--test/pig_1372117125028.log
```

And this is the details of the pig_137..log

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 7, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""

org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 7, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParserTokenManager.getNextToken(PigScriptParserTokenManager.java:3266)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.jj_ntk(PigScriptParser.java:1134)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:104)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:604)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
================================================================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got data like this:

```
2724    1919    2012-11-18T23:57:56.000Z    {(33.80981975),(-118.105289)}
2703    6401    2012-11-18T23:57:56.000Z    {(55.83525609),(-4.07733138)}
1200    4015    2012-11-18T23:57:56.000Z    {(41.49609152),(13.8411998)}
7104    9227    2012-11-18T23:57:56.000Z    {(-24.95351118),(-53.46538723)}
```

and I can do this:

```
A = LOAD 'my_tsv_data' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (id1:int, id2:int, date:chararray, loc:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(loc,'\\{|\\}|\\(|\\)','');                                                                                                 
C = LIMIT B 10;                                                                                                                                           
DUMP C;
```

Answer (score 2):

This error

```
ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 7, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""
```

came to me because I had used different types of quotation marks. I started with ' and ended with ´ or `, and it took quite a while to find what went wrong. So it had nothing to do with line 7 (my script was not so long, and I shortened data to four lines which naturally did not help), nothing to do with column 0, nothing to do with EOF of data, and hardly anything to do with " marks which I didn't use. So quite misleading error message.

I found the cause by using grunt - pig command shell.

Comment: This answer saved my day. That's a pretty misleading error message.